# Integral with residues

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Calculate integral
$$\oint\limits_{\gamma}\frac{e^z}{z^4+5z^3}dz$$
Where $\gamma$ is parameterization of one rotation of circle $A(0,2)$

So if I write the integral like this
$$\oint\limits_{\gamma}\frac{e^z}{z^3(z-5)}dz$$
We see that there is simple pole at $z=(5,0)$ and pole order of $3$ at $(0,0)$.

So isn't residue for the simple pole. Out side of $\gamma$.
\begin{align}\operatorname{Res}\limits_{z_0=5}&= \lim_{z\to 5} (z-5) f(z)\\
&= \lim_{z\to 5}(z-5) \frac{e^z}{z^3 (z-5)} \\
&=\lim_{z\to 5} \frac{e^z}{z^3}\\
&=\frac{e^5}{125}
\end{align}
And for the origo $(k=3)$
\begin{align} \operatorname{Res}\limits_{z_0=0}&= \frac{1}{(k-1)!}\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\partial^{k-1}}{\partial z^{k-1}}(z-0)^k f(z)\\
&= \frac 12 \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z^2}z^3\frac{e^z}{z^3 (z-5)} \\
&=\frac 12 \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{e^z ( (z-5)^2 - 2(z-6))}{(z-5)^2}\\
&=-\frac{37}{250}
\end{align}

So the integral value should be 
$$2\pi i (- 37/250) =-\frac{74 \pi i}{250}$$

Is this the right way to find the integral or should I have found the laurent series for  $f(z)$ or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simplier with the Laurent Formula indeed:

the only residue inside $\gamma$ is for $z=0$.

$$
\frac{\exp z}{(z-5)z^3}
= -\frac 15\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{z^m}{m!} \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n-3}5^{-n}
$$
hence the residual is
$$
-\frac 15 \left(
\frac1{0!} 5^{-2} + \frac1{1!} 5^{-1} + \frac1{2!} 5^{-0} 
\right)
= -\frac 15\times\frac{37}{50}
$$

and the integral is
$$\oint\limits_{\gamma}\frac{e^z}{z^4+5z^3}dz = -\frac{37\pi}{125}$$

Answer (score 2):

If by $A(0,2)$ you mean the circle $|z|= 2$, then $z = 5$ is not inside the circle, so you don't need to take into account the residue at $z=5$

Comment: Oh right! So the residue is zero there. I'll edit my post

Comment: So the correct answer should be $-74 \pi i /250$ then?

Comment: @ELEC yeah, if your computation of derivative is right, a typo: the order of derivative is $k-1$ not $k$

Comment: That is true! Luckily I derivated only twice despite the typo.

Comment: @ELEC yes, your mind follows the right way